# pg_ctl: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main" is not a database cluster directory

Tags: command-line, apt, server, postgresql

I'm following [this guide](https://buddylindsey.com/replication-with-postgresql-on-ubuntu.html) to do a replica server using postgres, I already made everything in a shell to automate it and seems fine, until I get to this command

```
pg_basebackup -h 192.168.1.103 -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -P -U replication
```

which I rewrote as

```
sudo -H -u postgres bash -c "pg_basebackup -h 192.168.1.103 -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/ -P -U replication"
```

However right when my shell gets to run that command linux suddenly just keeps working... for around 3 minutes until it gives up, the shell resumes the script and ends the job, needless to say the command that gets stuck didn't get me the folder I was asking on from the primary server to the secondary server, the postgres log file shows me this:

`pg_ctl: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main" is not a database cluster directory`

Running

```
pg_lsclusters
```

gets me

```
 Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
 10  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
 /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

So I'm clueless of what to do next since I can't find information about this error online

However I'm clueless of what to do next

Comment: The author of the script company's internal IP address is `192.168.1.103` for their SQL server. Is your company's SQL server internal address the same?

Comment: Im just using thge same IP this question to attempt not confuse whoever reads it, (Im using my own master server IP which i have verified multiple times) so i just left the one in the article in my example to not make noise